# Entity Framework Core Migrate Table from DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm wondering if this is even possible. I'm writing an app in MVC using ASP.NET Core and EF Core. For the most part I've been doing code-first migrations (that's all I know how to do, as yet) for my entities.

Someone added a table to the database I'm using, and rather than deleting their table and doing it the code-first way, I'd like to just bring their table over using a DB first migration.

Is that even possible to mix and match DB-first/code-first techniques?

If it is, how do I do it? I can't seem to find anything about bringing over just one table. Only migrating a whole database, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The steps are the following:

1. Right click on your Models folder.
2. Select Add -> Add new Item
3. In the Add New Item Window, select Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model. (This would create a new DbContext, but we going to merge the two DbContext) Click Add
4. In the Entity Data Model Wizard select Code First from database.
5. Select your connection String.
6. Click in no, exclude sensitive data...
7. Uncheck Save connection settings.
8. Click next
9. Select the new Table
10. Click finish

In this point VS would generate two files: a new DbContext and the model for the table.

Now open de new DbContext cut the DbSet of your model and paste in your original DBContext, too cut the content of the OnModelCreating method and paste at the end of the OnModelCreating method of your Original DbContext.

The final step is add a new Migration ignoring the changes.
For example:
Add-migration NewTableAdded -IgnoreChanges -verbose